# Extracting a tar file containing files with Chinese names will make the filenames illegible

Tags: compression, encoding, tar

On my Mac OS 10.6.8 I had a directory full of files that had Chinese filenames. I proceeded to run `tar czf mydir.tar.gz mydir`

Now when I untar it with `tar xzf mydir.tar.gz`, the extracted filenames are all jumbled and no longer the original format or encoding. How do I restore it? I've already lost the original directory so the compressed file is the only thing I can work with.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/60379/create-a-zip-tgz-in-linux-such-that-windows-han-proper-filenames) may be related.